# Europe/Warsaw is not the same as CEST

Tags: php, timezone

Can please someone explain why CEST != Europe/Warsaw in PHP?

```
var_dump((new DateTimeZone('CEST'))->getOffset(new DateTime())); // 3600
var_dump((new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'))->getOffset(new DateTime())); // 7200
```

Comment: `Central European Summer Time (CEST)` is `2` hours ahead and `Europe/Warsaw` is `1` hours ahead. Therefore there is difference of `3600s`

Comment: `$dateTime = new DateTime(‘now’, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
    echo $dateTime->format('T'); // CEST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Europe/Warsaw` is an IANA tz database identifier (which are used by PHP and many others).  It covers time in Poland, including all history of changes since 1880.  You can review the entire definition [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017b/europe#L2024-L2068).

`CEST` is just a time zone abbreviation.  Though it typically represents Central European Summer Time, which is UTC+2 today, it has historically also been used as an abbreviation for Central European *Standard* Time, which is UTC+1.  Today we use the abbreviation `CET` for this, but that has not always been the case. 
 More information on this is available in the PHP docs, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php#114161).

In general, looking up a time zone by its abbreviation alone is not reliable.